# How do I batch trees with optimized bark and leaf materials?

Tags: unity-game-engine, optimization, shader

I have some problems with batching trees. I'm using the default unity terrain system and trees. My problem is that trees won't get batched together (I've set up static, dynamic, and GPU instancing) and as I've inspected the frame debugger I've come to these results:

I used trees with the optimized bark material and optimized leaf material

What causes distinct draw call:

1- Wind

2- color and size variations for trees

draw call reason: non instanced properties set for instanced shader

if I remove Wind or variations the GPU instancing would work (I don't want to remove wind and variations), Is there any way to batch trees in this case?

Answer (score 0):

One of the best solution is that using the trees from the Unity not importing trees from outside the Unity.